# Resizing Browser

Tags: html, css

I created a website using html/css codes. The problem is that when I run it in another computer, the details of the website (DIVs) gets messed up. How do I make the arrangement of the details of the website be fixed so that the positioning of the details will not change?

CSS

```
.wrapper{
width: 1880px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.head {
height: 16%;
}
.opacity {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 19.7%;
right: 0.4%;
left: 0.4%;
bottom: 76%;
background-color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.6;
}
.opacity2 {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 91%;
right: 0.4%;
left: 0.4%;
bottom: 5%;
background-color: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.6;
}
.menu {
position: absolute;
height: 5%;
z-index: 4;
}
.main {
height: 62%;
z-index: 2;
}
.fixedfont {
font-size : 250%
}
.background {
position: absolute;
top: 19.5%;
right: 0.4%;
left: 0.4%;
bottom: 5%;
z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class = "background">
    <img src = "IMG_1594.jpg" width = "100%" height = "100%">
</div>
<div class = "opacity">
</div>
<div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "head">
        <center>
        <img src = "head.jpg" width = "100%" usemap = "#headmap">
        <map name = "headmap">
        <area shape = "rect" coords = "0,0,400,150" href = "united.html">
        </map>
        </center>
    </div>
    <hr size = "10" noshade color = "#f6c447">
    <hr size = "5" noshade color = "#092b51">
    <div class = "menu">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width = "14%">
                <center>
                <a href="united.html"><img src="home.png" onmouseover="this.src='home2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='home.png'" /></a>
                </center>
                </td>
                <td width = "14%">
                <center>
                <a href="about.html"><img src="about.png" onmouseover="this.src='about2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='about.png'" /></a>
                </center>
                </td>
                <td width = "14%">
                <center>
                <a href="project.html"><img src="projects.png" onmouseover="this.src='projects2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='projects.png'" /></a>
                </center>
                </td>
                <td width = "14%">
                <center>
                <a href="news.html"><img src="news.png" onmouseover="this.src='news2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='news.png'" /></a>
                </center>
                </td>
                <td width = "14%">
                <center>
                <a href="contact.html"><img src="contact.png" onmouseover="this.src='contact2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='contact.png'" /></a>
                </center>
                </td>
                </center>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class = "main">
    </div>
    <div class = "opacity2">
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <hr size = "5" noshade color = "#6699FF">
    <hr size = "10" noshade color = "#092b51">
</div>
<font face = "arial" color = "#092b51" size = "2">United Construction & Global Painters, Inc. Copyright, 2014.</font>
```

Comment: first wrap the `<title></title>` and `<style></style>` tags with a `<head></head>` tag.

Comment: Side note, don't use the `<center>` element. It doesn't exist anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: should have used some css responsive framework like zurb foundation , twitter bootsrap or purecss etc

Comment: `.wrapper{width: 1880px;` bad start.

Comment: Okay what should I do with .wrapper?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Why is it that?

Comment: Also, there is no guarantee about layout. While there are many things you can do style-wise to make it look consistent, remember that HTML and CSS are not (and never were) designed for a fixed display. Many markup elements are labeled "SHOULD" and "SHOULD NOT" which are recommendations, and "MAY" which are optional. The specific, final layout and rendering can be dramatically different visually yet still conforming.  Consider that scripts may be disabled through plugins or not present, that touch-based devices may not have a mouse to enter and exit,  that images may be replaced by alt text.

Comment: @Bryan Can you recommend ways on how to make my website look at least acceptable? should I make all the details be placed on the center of the browser?

Comment: Further looking through your markup.... Inside the HTML block the hr tags you use are no longer supported, td "width" is no longer supported, image alt tags are missing and image dimensions as percents are discouraged (you should use actual pixel sizes as images may not be available), the font tag is no longer supported,  etc. Your html looks like 1995. In the style, requiring that everything is "absolute" position can cause layout problems with the collapse rules, especially when browser screens are narrow. In your case 1880px width is crazy wide, especially considering mobile.

Comment: Yes. First, remove all the styling information from the HTML. You can use div around blocks and hr if you really did want a horizontal rule line. The use of an image map is questionable at best, they can be frustrating to get right. Then run the HTML through the HTML validator at w3schools. Ensure you include image sizes and alt text. Then use CSS to add your visual layout changes, again using the the CSS validator at w3schools and visually checking the results on the 5 major browsers (chrome, IE, firefox, Safari, Opera) at both very narrow widths and "normal" widths.

Comment: @Bryan any recommendations?

Comment: Third, add your script back in as visual flourishes; mouse events are eye candy that are frequently not visible thanks to tools like Ghostery and SafeScript and NoScript, and to mobile browsers not having a mouse. Ensure your site works correctly without javascript then use it for flair if you want. Finally, once you have all that in place, test it again on all the browsers both with JavaScript enabled and with it disabled, with images enabled and with images disabled. Test with browser widths as low as 320px (e.g. iphone 4) and allow users to grow to 5000 px wide if they want (retina 5k).

Comment: Work with the users, not against them.  I know news sites like to lock their content to 80 character width columns and use awful fonts if they detect mobile (assuming a tiny cell phone), they don't allow for high-res mobile devices. One of my mobile devices has a 1920x1080 screen, the other a 640x480 display. Don't force me into a bucket because your choice is probably wrong, let me and my own browser decide how to render.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how the wrapper is set to a certain pixel width. Try changing it to this

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but I get the same result when I resize the browser or open it in other PC.

Comment: You might just have to rewrite your code to be more efficient it looks great to me but browsers can be weird